# Serialize C# dynamic object to JSON object to be consumed by javascript

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

Based on the example [c# dynamic with XML](http://www.gotnet.biz/Blog/post/Fluent-XML-Parsing-Using-CSharp-Dynamic-Type-Part-2.aspx), I modified DynamicXml.cs and parsed my xml string.
the modified part is as follows

```
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (binder.Name == "Controls")
            result = new DynamicXml(_elements.Elements());
        else if (binder.Name == "Count")
            result = _elements.Count;
        else
        {
            var attr = _elements[0].Attribute(
                XName.Get(binder.Name));
            if (attr != null)
                result = attr.Value;
            else
            {
                var items = _elements.Descendants(
                    XName.Get(binder.Name));
                if (items == null || items.Count() == 0)
                    return false;
                result = new DynamicXml(items);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The xml string to parse:

```
               "< View runat='server' Name='Doc111'>" +
                    "< Caption Name='Document.ConvertToPdf' Value='Allow Conversion to PDF'></ Caption>" +
                    "< Field For='Document.ConvertToPdf' ReadOnly='False' DisplayAs='checkbox' EditAs='checkbox'></ Field>" +
                    "< Field For='Document.Abstract' ReadOnly='False' DisplayAs='label' EditAs='textinput'></ Field>" +
                    "< Field For='Document.FileName' ReadOnly='False' DisplayAs='label' EditAs='textinput'></ Field>" +
                    "< Field For='Document.KeyWords' ReadOnly='False' DisplayAs='label' EditAs='textinput'></ Field>" +
                    "< FormButtons SaveCaption='Save' CancelCaption='Cancel'></ FormButtons>" +
                "</ View>";
```

dynamic form = new DynamicXml(markup_fieldsOnly);

is there a way to serialize the content of this dynamic object(name value pairs inside dynamic) **form** as JSON object and sent to client side(browser)?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) works pretty well, though I've never used it myself.